Random failure to load load response data for iframe in Google Chrome
While trying to integrate a third party webview with an Angular application I am facing the following problem.
The iframe created by the third party script does not receive the data from server.
This problem is random and specific to Google Chrome - tested in latest standard version with no extensions or any unusual settings applied. It was not reproduced in Firefox or Safari browsers. No issue specific errors in console or failed network requests are shown.
The response tab in developer tools only shows [Failed to load response data. Request with the provided ID does not exist.], the timing tab shows the request as not finished but the response headers are loaded and the status is 200.
The request data is same in both successful and unsuccessful scenarios and as far as I know the server response is also same.
The sample application showing the issue can be seen on https://angular-ivy-nhtqam.stackblitz.io/ but requires an account and registered application with dropbox.
